# Double-commutator $[f,[f, - \Delta]] = -2 |\nabla f|^2.$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

This book (proof of Theorem 3.2) in chapter 3.1 claims [click me](https://books.google.de/books?id=kyjvCAAAQBAJ&pg=PP7&lpg=PP7&dq=ims%20localization%20formula&source=bl&ots=OgLTzx8dNJ&sig=YGUdl78B1hpyQs1HY4XW4_mA6Ss&hl=de&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAGoVChMImJi4uvnkyAIVZWdyCh2mgglZ#v=onepage&q=ims%20localization%20formula&f=false)
that an easy computation shows that $$[f,[f, - \Delta]] = -2 |\nabla f|^2.$$
where $[.,.]$ denotes the commutator. Unfortunately, I really don't see how one gets this easily out of it. Besides, the equation below this one is fairly direct to me.

Does anybody have an idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the commutator acts in a way similar to the derivative, therefore, e.g.
\begin{align}[f,[\partial_x^2,f]]&=[f,\partial_x\circ[\partial_x,f]+[\partial_x,f]\circ\partial_x]=
[f,\partial_x\circ f_x+f_x\circ\partial_x]=\\
&=\underbrace{[f,\partial_x]}_{=-f_x}\circ f_x+\partial_x\circ\underbrace{[f,f_x]}_{=0}+\underbrace{[f,f_x]}_{=0}\circ \partial_x+f_x\underbrace{\circ[f,\partial_x]}_{=-f_x}=-2f_x^2.
\end{align}

Comment: why is the commutator $[f, \partial_x]=-f_x,$ what happens to the term $f \partial_x$?

Comment: @Danielokw $[f,\partial_x]$ applied to a function $g$ gives $$ f \partial_x g-\partial_x(fg) = -f_x g.$$

Answer (score 2):

It's a good idea to be careful and act a commutator on a dummy function to figure out which it does when you are encountering it for the first time. The commutator may just act like a function being multiplied, e.g. $| \nabla f|^2 $, but it also may act like an operator, e.g. $f \Delta $. You probably won't be able to tell which it is intuitively, but your bases are covered if you always act the operator on a dummy function. You can see this by acting some simple example commutators, $[\partial,f]$ and $[\partial^2,f]$, on dummy function $g$:

\begin{align*}
[\partial,f]g = & \, (\partial f - f \partial)g &[\partial^2,f]g = & \, (\partial^2 f - f \partial^2)g \\
=& \, \partial (fg) - f \partial g & =& \, \partial^2 (fg) - f \partial^2 g\\
=& \, f \partial g + g \, \partial f -f\partial g & =& \, f \partial^2 g + 2 (\partial f)(\partial g) +g \, \partial^2 f -f\partial^2 g\\
=& \, g \, \partial f & =& \, 2 (\partial f)(\partial g) +g \, \partial^2 f\\
\therefore  [\partial,f]=& \, \partial f &\therefore [\partial^2,f] = & \, \partial^2 f + 2 (\partial f)\partial  
\end{align*}
So $[\partial,f]$ can be written as a function being multiplied, but $[\partial^2,f]$ cannot. Now we can repeat this with the commutator the OP described.

\begin{align*}
[f,[f,-\Delta]]g
=& \, (f[f,-\Delta]-[f,-\Delta]f)g\\
=& \, (-f^2 \Delta+2f\Delta f -\Delta f^2)g\\
=& \, -f^2 \Delta g +2f\Delta(fg)-\Delta(f^2 g)\\
=& \, -f^2 \Delta g +2f\Delta(fg)-(f\Delta(fg)+2\nabla f\cdot\nabla (fg)+fg \, \Delta f)\\ 
=& \, -f^2 \Delta g +f\Delta(fg)-2\nabla f\cdot\nabla (fg)-fg \, \Delta f\\
=& \, -f^2 \Delta g +f(f\Delta g+2\nabla f\cdot\nabla g+g \, \Delta f)-2\nabla f\cdot(f\nabla g+ g \nabla f)-fg \, \Delta f\\
= & -2 \nabla f \cdot g \nabla f\\
\therefore [f,[f,-\Delta]] =& -2 |\nabla f|^2
\end{align*}